# creating arraylist out of hashmap replaces all values from last recieved value

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I am creating new hashmap with arraylist in it. when new data comes, I do not know why it replaces all the previous values with new ones.

here is what I am doing but when I see in newly created arraylist of xdata, the values are same

```
xdata = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    xalldata = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<propertyData>>();
    xalldata.put("X1", allX1);
       xalldata.put("X2", allX2);
       xalldata.put("X3", allX3);
for (String x: xCordinates) {
    if (xAxis.get(x).size() > 0) {
        if (xalldata.get(x) == null) {
            t_tmp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            t_tmp.add(xalldata.get(x).get(0).x_max);
            xdata.put(x, t_tmp);
        } else {
            xdata.get(x).add(xalldata.get(x).get(0).x_max);
        }
    }
```

}

Expected output

```
key: x1 
Arraylist Data[34, 67, 98, 90]
key: x2 
Arraylist Data[78, 7, 633, 346]
```

Current out from code is

```
key: x1 
Arraylist Data[90, 90, 90, 90]
```

key: x1 
    Arraylist Data[34, 34, 34, 34]  // if 34 is new value it is replacing all old one as well..
The idea to extract the x_max from xalldata and create new arraylist that I can update with new values..when comes

at the end all the arraylist in xdata keeps only last values and replaces all values with new coming values. Thansl

Comment: This snippet does not make any sense:
`t_tmp.add(xalldata.get(x).get(0).x_max);`
This line throws a NullPointer exception, because xalldata.get(x) is null

Comment: xalldata is main hashmap where I have all the data, so I am just creatinf new one hahsmap with arraylist from it by appending new x_max everytime

Comment: `xalldata.get(x)` returns null if you get inside that `if` branch, right?
If so, `xalldata.get(x).get(0)` must throw a NullPointerException.

I don't see anything in your code that would create a new hashmap.

Comment: no, it it will not return null as it has key with the x..this code is running fine except old values are replaced by new one

Comment: If it does not return null, the `if` condition `if(xalldata.get(x) == null)` returns false, and this code is never executed

Comment: I have updated the question, I tried to be more clear..

Comment: It does not make it any clearer, I am afraid. There is still that NullPointerException problem. 
Additionally, this line `xalldata.get(x).get(0).x_max` always appends the same value to your array. 
That is, probably, the reason you are seeing the same values in the output.

Comment: hmm, but how can you avoid to append only last value or modify this code so that what I expect it works...

Comment: The problem is I still have no idea what it is "you expect". 
The code you quoted isn't making any sense. 
Perhaps, if you described what you are trying to do in words, it would make things a little clearer?

Comment: The idea is, I have data coming  in every 5 second from which I make hashmap named as xalldata of type  xalldata = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<propertyData>>(); , that saves key and respective arraylist of object propertyData, now I want to create new hashmap that will be of type xdata = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>(); in which I extract x_max value from old hashmap arraylist and add it to new hashmap arraylist. now I can extract x_max but everytime new x_max comes it replaces old values with new one, as I showed in exepected output..I hope now it is clear

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would add anything to xalldata. It is created empty on top, and always stays empty. What is x_max? Where does it come from, and how is its value determined?

Comment: that code I did not show as it is long filter for json string but that is working fine.., x_max is public variable in class propertyData ...

Comment: The point is, that your code always (when it does not crash with an NPE) gets *the same* value from xalldata: `xalldata.get(x).get(0).x_max` and appends that value to xdata.get(x).
Obviously, in the end you are going to have the list with a bunch of identical values. I don't understand why it surprises you. You append a bunch of identical values to the list ... and end up with a list of identical values.
Unless you are saying that xalldata.get(0).x_max is supposed to change somehow ... But the code you posted does not show that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I'm assuming you want to put the value found in xalldata (for the key x) in the new map :

```
for (String x: xCordinates) {
    if (xAxis.get(x).size() > 0) {
        if (xalldata.get(x) == null) {
            t_tmp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            t_tmp.add(xAxis.get(x).get(0).x_max); // was xalldata
            xdata.put(x, t_tmp);
        } else {
            xdata.put(xalldata.get(x)); // add the value from the old map to the
                                        // new map
            xdata.get(x).add(xAxis.get(x).get(0).x_max); // was xalldata
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but i am creating new hashmap xdata from alldata hashmap

Comment: no it is not correct,  xdata.put(x, t_tmp); if we see this, the arraylist for both hashmap is different one is arraylist of integer and other is some object....I hope I am corret in explaining

Comment: @user2323 Perhaps you should edit your question and show the declaration of all the variables involved in your code. Also show an example of the input and the desired output.